# Use XML query as part of WHERE predicate

Tags: sql-server, xpath, sql-server-2012

I need to include an XML query as part of the WHERE predicate in a SELECT statement.

I have this structure:

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (typeId int, xmlCol xml);

INSERT INTO @tmp 
    (typeId, xmlCol) 
VALUES 
    (1, '<search><groups><g id="25" /><g id="26" /></groups></search>'),
    (1, '<search><groups><g id="250" /><g id="9" /></groups></search>'),
    (2, '<search><groups><g id="25" /><g id="12" /><g id="125" /></groups></search>');

SELECT * FROM @tmp;
```

But I need to pull out rows where `typeId=1` AND where the XML data contains `<g id="25" />`.   So in my example I'd only see the first row in the result set.

I'd prefer an XML query rather than casting to nvarchar and using `LIKE`, if possible.  I tried this but just get a syntax error:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    @tmp
WHERE
    (typeId = 1) AND
    (xmlCol.query('/search/groups/g[@id=25])'))
```

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected, near ')'.

I've been searching for examples but cannot find XML queries being used in this manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you must use `xmlCol.exist` instead of query.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    @tmp
WHERE
    (typeId = 1) AND
    (xmlCol.exist('/search/groups/g[@id=25]') = 1)
```

Comment: That returns an error: *XQuery [@tmp.xmlCol.exist()]: No more tokens expected at the end of the XQuery expression. Found ')'.*

Answer (score 2):

Use `xmlcol.exist`. Something like this.

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (typeId int, xmlCol xml);

INSERT INTO @tmp 
    (typeId, xmlCol) 
VALUES 
    (1, '<search><groups><g id="25" /><g id="26" /></groups></search>'),
    (1, '<search><groups><g id="250" /><g id="9" /></groups></search>'),
    (2, '<search><groups><g id="25" /><g id="12" /><g id="125" /></groups></search>');

 DECLARE @id int = 25

SELECT * FROM @tmp
WHERE typeId = 1 
    AND xmlCol.exist('search/groups/g[@id= sql:variable("@id")]') = 1
```

Comment: Lovely example with variable.  Thank you very much.